# change font size of HTML5 input type date popup calendar

Tags: html, datepicker

Is there an easy way to increase the font size? Every attempt just increases the font size *in the input box*, but not in the **calendar day selector.**

[image]

Comment: What browser is this on? Every browser implements their own version of the `date` input type, and some don't even have a calendar day selector as part of it.

Comment: Chrome, and I'll probably move to a compatible plug-in that can be used on all browsers. But let's say I only had to care about Chrome, how would I do this?